# Don't understand cause of this AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'setimage'

Tags: python, image, turtle-graphics, appjar

The code I have is:

```
import time
import turtle
from turtle import *
from random import randint

#GUI options
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1000,1000)
screen.setimage("eightLane.jpg")
title("RACING TURTLES")
```

The error message that comes up is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/bradley/Desktop/SDD/coding term 1 year 11/8 lane
experementaiton.py", line 14, in <module>
    screen.setimage("eightLane.jpg") AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'setimage'
```

Any advice is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want requires a fairly involved workaround (two of them actually) because it requires using the `tkinter` module to do part of it (because that's what the `turtle`-graphics module uses internally to do its graphics), and `turtle` doesn't have a method in it called `setscreen()`, as you've discovered via the `AttributeError`.

The complicate matters further, the `tkinter` module doesn't support `.jpg`. format images, so yet another workaround is needed to overcome that limitation, which requires needing to also use the `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) to convert the image into a format `tkinter` does support.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from turtle import *
import turtle

# GUI options
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(1000, 1000)

pil_img = Image.open("eightLane.jpg")  # Use PIL to open .jpg image.
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_img)  # Convert it into something tkinter can use.

canvas = turtle.getcanvas()  # Get the tkinter Canvas of this TurtleScreen.
# Create a Canvas image object holding the tkinter image.
img_obj_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_img, anchor='center')

title("RACING TURTLES")

input('press Enter')  # Pause before continuing.
```